# How to create an error page to a QueryException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm working on a commercial application and I've created Blade files for several kinds of HTTP errors. They are placed in `/resources/views/errors` and are working fine for authorization (503.blade.php), page not found (404.blade.php), and so on.

I've created files for 400, 403, 404, 500 and 503, until now.
The issue is when a `QueryException` is thrown. In this case, *"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."* appears.

For example, considering that `name` cannot be null, when I do something like this, Laravel throws a `QueryException`:

```
User::create([
          'name' => null,
          'email' => 'some@email.com'
]);
```

The exception would be:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert
>   into `users` (`nome`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (,
>   some@email.com, 2018-02-09 12:10:50, 2018-02-09 12:10:50))

I don't want *"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."* to appear to the end user, I want to show a custom page. What kind of error file do I need to create to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Just set the debug mode to false in `env` for production so users will not see this.

Comment: To @TheAlpha, I have already done that. I don't want to show "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.", I want to show a custom page. I've edited the question to explain this better.

Comment: remove Whoops then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this in your controller:**

```
try {
    User::create([
          'name' => null,
          'email' => 'some@email.com'
    ]);
} catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    // show custom view
    //Or
    dump($e->errorInfo);
}
```

**To catch all Query Exceptions:**

You need to customize the `render()` method of `App\Exceptions\Handler`, as stated in the [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors).

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ( $e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException ) {
        // show custom view
        //Or
        dump($e->errorInfo);
    } 
   return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is a good way to do it, but is there a generic way to achieve this? Suppose that I don't know where is it going to happen.

Comment: This works fine! The only thing I had to change is that I needed to return parent method and not throw the exception again.

Comment: @ElMynx great!. Please accept the answer if it helped you